# Keep getting 404 in spring boot endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning spring boot, I made a simple GET endpoint but whenever I request on that endpoint I keep getting 404.

Below is my code:
Student.Controller.java

```
package student;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class StudentController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return "This is String";
    }
}
```

Project Structure:
[image]

Comment: What endpoint are you calling? a 404 makes it sound like what you are calliing is different than whats mapped

Comment: localhost:800/home

Comment: Have you checked the default port?
Otherwise could you please provide us the package hierarchy of your project?

Comment: I have added it in the question

Comment: Your controller is not being picked up by component scan probably because of where you placed it, You will need to explicitly provide it with the @ComponentScan annotation.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Your controller should be under this package, com.example.demo
You can simply create a new package named controllers and place your controller there, the hierarchy will be => com.example.demo.controllers
This way, your controller will be picked up by spring IoC Container after scanning

Answer (score 0):

If you add @ComponentScan({"student"}) annotation on DemoApplication class it should work. You can also create your packages such as controller, service, repository ... under com.example.demo, then you don't have to add additional annotations for component scanning.

Follow this project structuring advice: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html